# Get contributions.json on Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api, gitlab-ce

How can I get `contributions.json` of myself in a Gitlab CI pipeline with private contributions if "show private contributions" is off in the settings?

https://gitlab.com/users/GITLAB_USERNAME/calendar.json shows both public and private contributions if the logged in user is GITLAB_USERNAME.

https://gitlab.com/users/GITLAB_USERNAME/calendar.json shows only public contributions if the logged in user is not GITLAB_USERNAME and "show private contributions" is off for GITLAB_USERNAME.

I can do this with `curl --cookie "_gitlab_session=..." https://gitlab.com/users/GITLAB_USERNAME/calendar.json` where I have obtained the cookie by logging in through the web interface. The session cookie expires after 1 week by default.

I want an automated way to do this through a CI pipeline without simulating a log in and storing my password as a variable (insecure, and if I change my password, I need to update all of them).

I have tried using `CI_JOB_TOKEN` for authentication (like I do with API: `curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $CI_JOB_TOKEN" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects"`), but only the public contributions are showing up.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it using `calendar.json` *endpoint*. You need to use **[events](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/events.html) api**.

You can collect all your events using personal token and [events](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/events.html) api `curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" https://gitlab.com/api/v4/users/:id/events`

User id can be found using: `https://gitlab.com/api/v4/users?username=YOUR_USERNAME`

Instead of job token use [personal access token](https://gitlab.com/profile/personal_access_tokens) to get access to gitlab api.

To [filter out](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/events.html#list-currently-authenticated-users-events) your results use parameters according to your needs. There is a lot more data than when gathering from `https://gitlab.com/users/GITLAB_USERNAME/calendar.json` url so you would need to process it.

NOTE:

`https://gitlab.com/users/GITLAB_USERNAME/calendar.json` is **not api** url but gitlab endpoint so gitlab token **won't work** for it.

Comment: I've tried `curl https://gitlab.com/users/GITLAB_USERNAME/calendar.json?private_token=<your_access_token>` and `curl --header "Private-Token: <your_access_token>" https://gitlab.com/users/GITLAB_USERNAME/calendar.json`. Both of them only return the public data.

Comment: As I wrote calendar.json won't do. you need to use `https://gitlab.com/api/v4/users/:id/events` to get more info.